# Material UI X Date Picker - Callback when user clicks day in calendar select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using the [DateTimePicker](https://v5.mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-time-picker/) in material ui, v5 (for both MUI itself and MuiX, which I know is 1 major version behind).   I need to be able to hook into the callback that is fired when the user clicks a day in the calendar select:

[image]

While the `DateTimePicker` sports an `onChange` prop, this is fired when the user changes the date via the calendar UI, *or* via the text input.  I need a way to capture when the user has clicked on the date buttons in the calendar view.  The goal is that they should be able to select the day, and when they do, the hour should automatically be set to 00:00.

My thoughts are to capture the onClick handler of the day buttons, and within it, get the new date value, adjust the hours/minutes, and then set the state to that adjusted date.  I had dug through their documentation, but there doesn't seem to be a way to capture this.  If the `onChange` prop had some type of `reason` or `origin` property that helped me determine where the change came from (text input vs calendar select), this would also help.  Here's a quick code sample:

```js
 <DateTimePicker
  inputFormat="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"
  value={date}
  renderInput={params => (
    <TextField {...params} />
  )}
  onChange={e => {
    // fires when user types, or uses picker
    setDate(e);
  }}
  // I really only want a day picker, but need to 
  // use DateTimePicker to enable hours in the text input
  views={["day"]} 
  components={{
    ActionBar: ({ onAccept }: PickersActionBarProps) => (
      <Button
        onClick={() => {
          setDate(default);
          onAccept();
        }}
      >
        Reset to Default
      </Button>
    )
  }}
/>
```

Is there a way to capture just the onClick handler of the day buttons here, with the new date value?

Answer (score 0):

Well I asked this a bit prematurely.  It turns out the `onAccept` prop does exactly this.  It will fire when you input a date using the calendar picker, but not when you input a date using the text input.  From there, you can intercept the value and adjust it:

```js
<DateTimePicker
  ...
  value={value}
  onAccept={e => {
    const value = new Date(e);
    value.setHours(0);
    value.setMinutes(0);
    value.setSeconds(0);
    value.setMilliseconds(0);
    setValue(e);
  }}
/>
```

Will leave this here in case it ever helps anyone in the future.